# Time display at x axis instead of date display in highstock

Tags: jquery, mysql, date, highcharts

I'm getting time in this format 18:30:00.000 at X axis instead of date, How to display Date at X axis? I'm inserting the date as varchar and in this format 
2015-04-01  into the database.
Then I'm fetching using this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.000000' from UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*1000) as unixdate,".$type." from h_stats where category='Hits' order by unixdate asc";
```

And creating CSV file having date format as highcharts. And I'm using the below jquery property to display the date at X axis using highcharts. But Im not getting it.

```
$('#hits').highcharts('StockChart', {

     xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        month: '%Y-%m',
        year: '%Y'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you use PHP to connect with database, so better is get data from database and convert to json. Then load this in jaascript to highcharts. In SO, you will find many similar topics.

Comment: Yes i have converted to highcharts date format.Now it is working fine Thanks